# Persisting Salesforce OAuth Token

Tags: salesforce, omniauth

I'm trying to contact Salesforce REST API from my rails app and i'm authorizing my app through OAuth2. I'm just confused on the lifetime of the returned OAuth token. I assume this OAuth token is immortal and I can safely store it in DB for future API calls. Please comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 tokens the access token which you need to use to make API calls, and is relatively short lived, and a refresh token which is a long lived token that you should persist and can later use via the [token service](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm) to get new access tokens.